# How to setState with Firebase user data?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, this

The below React code is a component with two state items - user and license. Both are empty string that change when a user logs in.

Using Firebase's onAuthStateChanged method inside of React's compoentDidMount method works great for user info.  The user state changes without issue.  But inside those methods I also call the database for the current user's license.  The data is fetched without issue but I keep getting an error saying setState is undefined.

I added bind(this) to setState and that didn't change anything. Same error.

I feel like it's an issue with the "this" keyword but I can't figure out exactly what it is.

Here's the code...

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    user: '',
    license: ''
  };
}

componentDidMount() {

  auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user){

      this.setState({user});
      let userId = auth.currentUser.uid;

      firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        var license = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().license);

        this.setState({license});
      });

    }else{
      console.log('no user');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the classical scope issue of 'this' object. You will have to bind the 'this' to the function like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + 
  userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var license = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().license);

    this.setState({license});
  }.bind(this);
```

Comment: Since OP is already using `=>` in the code, that's another option for the nested function too.

Comment: Yep. Thank you kind stranger.